# p:graphicImage with cache="false" changes on action on local wildfly, but not once deployed to openshift, why?

Tags: primefaces, openshift, wildfly

I have a local wildfly 8.1 server with primefaces 5.0.4. On it I have a jsf web app with a facelets page with p:graphicImage cache="false" and its DefaultStreamedContent method in the backing bean. I have an action, that invokes some code that changes the image url and refreshes the image parent. It all works like a charm on my local server. The problem is when I deploy the app to openshift. Everything works fine except for the dynamic image, it keeps returning the same image, even though in my debugging code all is well, I can see the new url change and with an inspect element in chrome dev tools the image dynamic url uid changes after each refresh: 
/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties.xhtml?ln=primefaces&pfdrid=5SVKvQrbpnnQ%2Bp%2B1DV8qP80xqOBb22iRPsVFmH9qJB8%3D&pfdrid_c=false&uid=bb89b7f1-7eae-44ba-807b-118e29ce4c7c

And after the refresh:

/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties.xhtml?ln=primefaces&pfdrid=54SVKvQrbpnnQ%2Bp%2B1DV8qP80xqOBb22iRPsVFmH9qJB8%3D&pfdrid_c=false&uid=d50a9397-f836-415d-9679-16c028d4aadd

How can the image still be cached?